# How to convert XDocument to FileStream in C#

Tags: c#, sharepoint, filestream, linq-to-xml

I have seen this post [How to correctly open a FileStream for usage with an XDocument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/277783/how-to-correctly-open-a-filestream-for-usage-with-an-xdocument) but it doesn't help me since I don't have the path to the file on the local hard drive. This XDocument is getting passed to another computer so the BaseURI is worthless.

I want to know how to convert an XDocument into a FileStream without using a local file path.

Comment: This question doesn't make sense - an existing `XDocument` is not associated with a (file) stream or file path. You can only serialize it if you provide either.

Comment: Ehh? A FileStream needs a filename... An XDocument can be saved to a NetworkStream.

Comment: What I am ultimately trying to do is upload an XDocument to a Document Library in SharePoint

Comment: So don't call that a FileStream.

Comment: @MeyerDenney: So what does the API for uploading to SharePoint look like?

Comment: If you look at this post at the sharepoint stackexchange site you will see the code needed to upload a file to a document library. It needs a FileStream object. http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/21383/how-to-upload-an-xdocument-to-a-document-library-without-a-local-hard-drive-path

Comment: So it's actually a cross-post.

Comment: It looks like the method being called in that example does not expect a FileStream, just a Stream.  So using Jacob's answer below, you could write your xml data to a memory stream and then pass that.  Here are the docs for that method:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms412937.aspx

Comment: I think this question can be deleted since it is now answered on SharePoint.SE: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/21383/how-to-upload-an-xdocument-to-a-document-library-without-a-local-hard-drive-path/21388#21388

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A `FileStream` is used to write directly to a file, so if you don't have a file path, you don't have a `FileStream`.

You can, however, write to other streams, like a `MemoryStream`:

```
using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
{
    yourDocument.Save(stream);
}
```

Comment: Ouch. That's sending it to dev/nul.

Comment: Ha, yeah.  Obviously you'd actually do something with the stream before the end of the `using` block or use a different stream altogether (recent comments show he actually needs to upload to Sharepoint).

Comment: Indeed, but saving it to a MemStream is just moving it around... Not clear if it's progress to have a `byte[]`

Comment: In the case with Sharepoint, no, but some APIs want a byte array.  I know nothing about Sharepoint's APIs and what they require for input.