# how to load data from XML file directly, instead of creating XML file by tring builder

Tags: c#, xml, xmldocument, xmlreader

I am working on StringBuilder to create XML document. I want to give directly input as XML file and get the data from it, instead of building the xml file.

```
           string namespaceUri = "NamespaceURI";
           System.Text.StringBuilder content = new StringBuilder();
           string First = "Hello World.This is Fisrt field";
           content.AppendFormat("<{0} xmlns=\"{1}\">", "rootelementname", namespaceUri);
           content.AppendFormat("<{0} xmlns=\"{1}\">{2}</{0}>", "first", namespaceUri, First);
           content.AppendFormat("</{0}>", "rootelementname");
           string data = content.ToString();
```

outputXML file created using this as follows

```
    <rootelementname xmlns="namespaceUri">
        <first>Hello World.This is Fisrt field</first>            
    </rootelementname>
```

if i have above  xml file directly,underpath "E:\abcd\source.xml
how can i load that source.xml into "data" variable directly.

Please share your thoughts on this.

Thank you

Comment: Probably best to use an XDocument. Have a look at this article:-
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/277783/how-to-correctly-open-a-filestream-for-usage-with-an-xdocument

Comment: The [Xml.Namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y3y47afh.aspx) also has several types that can be used to work with Xml in case you don't want or need to use Linq To XML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following:

```
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.Load(@"E:\abcd\source.xml");

string data = xmlDoc.OuterXml;
```

The above is just a sample, in your code please handle exceptions accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be using a stringbuilder to serialize your XML. Try using an XDocument. Have a look at this article which explains in more detail:-
[How to correctly open a FileStream for usage with an XDocument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/277783/how-to-correctly-open-a-filestream-for-usage-with-an-xdocument)

Answer (score 0):

Use `System.Xml.XmlDocument` to load and save Xml. [Check this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.aspx).

You can use `XmlDocument.Load()` method to load xml from any directory. Check [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/875kz807.aspx)